# Rake aborted! cannot load such file -- arel/visitor/mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

When I try to run *Rake* (also with *Rails* commands) commands I got this error :

```
Rake aborted! cannot load such file -- arel/visitor/mysql
/config/application.rb:7:in <top (required)>
/Rakefile:4:in 'require_relative'
```

MySql database works perfectly, and I've added gem 'mysql2' in Gemfile.

Using *--trace* argument :

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- arel/visitors/mysql
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/arel/visitors.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/arel.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/home/sneffar/working-dir/permission/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sneffar/working-dir/permission/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/sneffar/working-dir/permission/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/sneffar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Ruby --version : 2.6.6
Rails --version : 6.0.3.1
Rake --version: 13.0.1

Comment: have you tried with `bundle exec` ?

Comment: Yes, it shows the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should remove arel:

```
gem uninstall arel
```

After that run:

```
bundle install
```

This should fix problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with this and agree with Nezir.
I believe that in my case, this happened because of such actions:
MySQL 5.7.30 -> MySQL 8.0.20 -> MySQL 5.7.30
The first time I had MySQL 5.7.30 it was fine with
bundle exec rake db:create db:structure:load

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error while working with a legacy application, and here is the solution which worked for me. Hope this will work for you.

https://gist.github.com/SahSantoshh/fffbfbaa91f82b46ef8aa39922ee889e

- Uninstall ruby
- reinstall ruby
- if db is running then It's fine if not, then run MySQL 5.7 using docker https://gist.github.com/SahSantoshh/8ff41ce4dd57305358e98d43adff76b1
- hit bundle
- run rake db:migrate